# How can i invoke-command successfully on a remote server to Add-WebConfigurationProperty

Tags: powershell, iis, remote-server, webdav

I saw few questions regarding something similar to mine, however I think that WebAdministration module cmdlets might have a bit more ambiguity in them.

**What I'm trying to do:**
Execute the following on a remote server:

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location "$FBFolderName/User/$Username" -filter "system.webServer/webdav/authoringRules" -name "."
Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location "$FBFolderName/User/$Username" -filter "system.webServer/webdav/authoringRules" -name "." -value @{users="$DomainUser";access='Read,Write,Source';path='*'}
```

These work perfectly fine when I run them on the server itself, and also work perfectly fine when I run them interactively creating a New-PSSession

When I run the following script non-interactively, however, the error I receive seems to point that the those instructions are running locally, and not on the remote server in question:

```
$FBFolderName = "FB Demo"
$Username = "user"
$AllUsersRole = "DOMAIN\GTM All Users"
$DomainUser= 'DOMAIN\' + $Username

$s = New-PSSession -computerName server.domain.local
$finalcommand = Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location "$FBFolderName/User/$Username" -filter "system.webServer/webdav/authoringRules" -name "."
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { Import-module WebAdministration; $finalcommand }
$finalcommand = Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location "$FBFolderName/User/$Username" -filter "system.webServer/webdav/authoringRules" -name "." -value @{users="$DomainUser" access='Read,Write,Source';path='*'}
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { $finalcommand }
Remove-PSSession $s
```

When running non-interactively, I receive the following error:

```
Remove-WebConfigurationProperty : Filename: 
Error: Unrecognized configuration path 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/FB Demo'
At line:1 char:17
+ $finalcommand = Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-WebConfigurationProperty], FileNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Provider.RemoveConfigurationPropertyCommand
```

This does make sense in that it's trying to find a non-existent collection on the local machine.

My questions are:

1. Am I doing something wrong to allow this to run remotely?
2. Before trying to develop this method, I was using psexec with appcmd to do the same, which works, but takes a long time for psexec to establish connection.
3. Am I taking the wrong approach? and is there a better method to do the same on a remote server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are storing your command in a local variable, which is unknown in the remote session:

```
$finalcommand = Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location "$FBFolderName/User/$Username" -filter "system.webServer/webdav/authoringRules" -name "."
```

Store all your commands in a scriptblock:

```
 $commandScriptBlock= {
     Import-module WebAdministration
     Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location "$FBFolderName/User/$Username" -filter "system.webServer/webdav/authoringRules" -name "."
  }
```

And call the scriptblock via:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $commandScriptBlock
```

As an alternative you may also pass `$finalcommand` as an argument to the `Invoke-Command` cmdlet. See this [link](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/12/29/how-to-pass-arguments-for-remote-commands/) for further informatin about how to do this.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you Moerwald!
I had to do further research to get everything to work, and the answer was a combination of both your suggestions. I'll post the full solution as an answer for those who might be facing the same issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

For those curious about the full solution. Please see below.

The syntax for Add-WebConfigurationProperty and Add-WebConfigurationProerty was quite tedious. Hint: Make sure to not inadvertently add a "/" at the end of MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST. It will drive you crazy with misleading errors.

```
$ServerFQDN = "server.domain.local"
$FBFolderName = "FolderName" # This is the name of your IIS Site
$Username = "User"
$DomainUser = "DOMAIN\User"
$s = New-PSSession -computerName $ServerFQDN
    $commandScriptBlock = { 
        Import-Module WebAdministration
        Write-Host "Setting WebDAV Permissions ..."
        Try { 
            Remove-WebConfigurationProperty -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -pspath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" -Location "$($args[0])/User/$($args[1])" -Filter "system.webServer/webdav/authoringRules" -name "." 
            Write-Host -NoNewline "   Removing All Users from Authoring Rules ..."
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green " [ OK ]"
        }
        Catch {
            Write-Host -NoNewline "   Removing All Users from Authoring Rules ..."
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red " [ ERROR ] "
            Write-Output $($_.Exception.Message)
        }

        Try {  
            Add-WebConfigurationProperty -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -pspath "MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST" -Location "$($args[0])/User/$($args[1])" -Filter "system.webServer/webdav/authoringRules" -name "." -value @{users="$($args[2])";access='Read,Write,Source';path='*'}
            Write-Host -NoNewline "   Adding user $($args[2]) to Authoring Rules ..."
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green " [ OK ]"
        }
        catch  {
            Write-Host -NoNewline "   Adding user $($args[2]) to Authoring Rules ..."
            Write-Host -ForegroundColor red " [ ERROR ] "
            Write-Output $($_.Exception.Message)
        }
    }
    Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $commandScriptBlock -ArgumentList $FBFolderName,$Username,$DomainUser
    Remove-PSSession $s
```